# MBP 13" 2015 - OSX Mojave freezes fully

Tags: macos, freeze, crash, macbook-pro, macos-mojave

Lately my MacBook Pro 13" Early 2015 running Mojave 10.14.6 freezes completely on a more or less regular basis (about 3-5 times a week).
It's a full freeze i.e. nothing works any more and the only option is to hold down the power button for a few seconds until it restarts.
After the restart there is no crash report or anything like that and I haven't been able to track down any logs to narrow down the problem either (`~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` is empty for example).

Is there any way to narrow down the issue?

Until it freezes it behaves perfectly, no issues at all. After the restart it works just fine again too. I feel it might have occurred mostly while I was watching something in the evenings (netflix, twitch ...) although I'm not 100% sure on that.

Any advice on how to track down the issue would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I see this a little bit tumbleweed. Cross post in apple.stackexchange.com in a few days, but don't say I told you. :D

Answer (score 0):

I run the same OS version in the same, or almost the same hardware:

> MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Fabulous piece of hardware.
No weird issues from my side, apart from having recently got a new battery [because the previous one started growing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/364648/146438).

1. Run Ubuntu Live on your laptop, hang around for a while, see what happens.

   - If does weird stuff, back up your data, if you can, if you haven't a reasonable data backup at the moment. send it to the repair shop asking to find a hardware issue.
   - If doesn't do weird stuff, continue to 2.1.
2. "But I don't want to run Ubuntu".

   1. Back up your data, if you can, if you haven't a reasonable data backup at the moment.
   2. Format. Reinstall macOS.
   3. If stays wrong, send it to the repair shop asking to find a hardware issue. You can go directly here.